# Python: How to get all default values from argparse

Tags: python, argparse, default-value

When module `optparse` is used, then I can get all default values for all command line arguments like this:

```
import optparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage='pokus --help')
    parser.add_option("-d", "--debug", action='store_true', dest="debug",
                      default=False, help='Enabling debugging.')
    options, args = parser.parse_args()
    print(parser.defaults)
```

Since `optparse` is deprecated it is wise to rewrite your code to use `argparse` module. However I can't find any way how to get all default values of all command line arguments added to parser object:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='pokus --help')
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", action='store_true', dest='debug',
                        default=False, help='Enabling debugging.')   
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # <---- How to get default values for all arguments here?
    # Not: vars(args)
```

I want to get all default values when I run program with (`./app.py -d`) or without any command line argument (`./app.py`).

Comment: The default values are set on the `args` object when switches are omitted. Do you need to have access to those for anything else?

Comment: So in your example, `args.debug` is set to `False` when you don't run the program with `-d`. What is your usecase for needing to know the default is `False` when you run with `-d`?

Comment: Have you considered using [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/)?

Comment: I found solution, when I run `defaults = vars(parser.parser-args([]))`, then I get dictionary with all default values. BTW: I need it, when I have lot of arguments and I need to distinguish between default values and values specified at command line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you do not want to parse an empty input string, you can use the method `get_default` in the `parser` object:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='pokus --help')
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", action='store_true', dest='debug',
                        default=False, help='Enabling debugging.')   
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # To get a single default:
    d_default = parser.get_default('d')

    # To get all defaults:
    all_defaults = {}
    for key in vars(args):
        all_defaults[key] = parser.get_default(key)

    # Edit: Adding an alternative one-liner (using dict comprehension):
    all_defaults = {key: parser.get_default(key) for key in vars(args)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like a working solution too.

Comment: I had to use parser.get_default('debug') for this to work.

Comment: Obviously this fails if there are required arguments.

Answer (score 16):

I found solution:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='pokus --help')
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", action='store_true', dest='debug',
                        default=False, help='Enabling debugging.')
    parser.add_argument("-e", "--example", action='store', dest='example',
                        default="", help='Example of argument.')
    # Arguments from command line and default values
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    # Only default values
    defaults = vars(parser.parse_args([]))
```

Then you can compare `args` and `defaults` values and distinguish between default values and values from command line.

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat late to the party, but this is a function (with bonus unittest) that I've used in a couple of cases to get hold of the default arguments without having to parse first (parsing first can be annoying if you have required arguments that aren't available yet)

```
def get_argparse_defaults(parser):
    defaults = {}
    for action in parser._actions:
        if not action.required and action.dest != "help":
            defaults[action.dest] = action.default
    return defaults

def get_argparse_required(parser):
    required = []
    for action in parser._actions:
        if action.required:
            required.append(action.dest)
    return required

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
optional_defaults_dict = get_argparse_defaults(parser)
required_list = get_argparse_required(parser)
```

---

```
class TestDefaultArgs(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_args(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('positional_arg')
        parser.add_argument('--required_option', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('--optional_with_default', required=False, default="default_value")
        parser.add_argument('--optional_without_default', required=False)

        required_args = get_argparse_required(parser)
        self.assertEqual(['positional_arg', 'required_option'], required_args)


        default_args = get_argparse_defaults(parser)
        self.assertEqual({'optional_with_default': 'default_value',
                          'optional_without_default': None},
                         default_args)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I also needed to make the default objects the correct type: `default = action.default;if action.type is not None:  default = action.type(default);defaults[action.dest] = default;` Note that the none check is needed for boolean flags.

Answer (score 2):

For your information, here's the code, at the start of parsing that initializes the `defaults`:

```
def parse_known_args(...):
    ....
    # add any action defaults that aren't present
    for action in self._actions:
        if action.dest is not SUPPRESS:
            if not hasattr(namespace, action.dest):
                if action.default is not SUPPRESS:
                    setattr(namespace, action.dest, action.default)

    # add any parser defaults that aren't present
    for dest in self._defaults:
        if not hasattr(namespace, dest):
            setattr(namespace, dest, self._defaults[dest])
    ...
```

So it loops through the `parser._actions` list, collecting the `action.default` attribute. (An `action` is a `Action` class object that was created by the `parser.add_argument` method.).  It also checks `self._defaults`.  This is the dictionary modified by a `parse.set_defaults` method.  That can be used to set `defaults` that aren't linked directly to an action.

After parsing the command line, default strings in the namespace may be evaluated (with the `action.type`), turning, for example a `default='1'` into an integer 1.

Handling of defaults in `argparse` isn't trivial.  Your `parse_args([])` probably is simplest, provided the parser is ok with that (i.e. doesn't have any required arguments).

I don't know now `optparse` sets the `defaults` attribute.  There is a non-trival method, `optparse.OptionParser.get_default_values`.

Answer (score 1):

For the above example:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='pokus --help')
   parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", action='store_true', dest='debug',
                    default=False, help='Enabling debugging.')
```

**A.** To get all the values with their defaults in a `tuple` format:

```
In[1]: args = parser.parse_known_args()[0]
In[2]: args._get_kwargs()
Out[1]: [('debug', False)]
```

to access to each item:

```
In[3]: args.debug
Out[2]: False
```

**B.** To get the values and their default as `dictionary` format

```
In[4]: dict_args = parser.parse_known_args()[0].__dict__
In[5]: dict_args
Out[3]: {'debug': False}
```

And to access each key:

```
In[6]: dict_args['debug']
Out[4]: False
```

Or print them iteratively:

```
In[7]: for key in dict_args:
...        print('value for %s is: %s'% (key, dict_args[key]))

Out[5]: value for debug is: False
```